# How Can I merge code from production to SVN?

Tags: svn

We have two projects. We have one setup in SVN and the other we have directly deployed on production server. How can I setup the code from production server into SVN repository?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Just import the unversioned code from  your prod server to your code repository (SVN). See details [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html).

```
svn import [PATH] URL
```

import is nothing but a combo command for `add` and `commit`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new repository, copy the production code into the new repository, add/ignore files as you please, commit.